# Entity Framework ICollection creates internal table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Using .NET Entity Framework Code First I have two simple models:

```
public class Car
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

Doing this a third table is created with the name : **LocationCars**.

Is there anyway to customize the name of this generated table ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to use [FluentApi](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) to customize the many-to-many relation

From the turorial

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Locations)
                .WithMany(l => l.Cars)
                .Map(cl =>
                        {
                        cl.MapLeftKey("CarId");
                        cl.MapRightKey("LocationId");
                        cl.ToTable("YOUR_TABLE_NAME");
                        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create manual many-to-many mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
    .HasMany(c => c.Locations)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(l => l.MapLeftKey("CarId").MapRightKey("LocationId").ToTable("TableNameHere"));
```